# Recommendations for Commutative Algebra Software?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, math-software

I'd like a software that I can use to work with commutative algebra, specifically to figure out S-Polynomials, Buchberger's Algorithm, etc.

I have Mathematica; if anyone could refer me to a package, it'd be awesome. Currently, I've checked out a package that the authors of *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* have offered (it's from the Amherst College website) but there are way too many issues that need some cleaning up with the code.

Is there anything a bit more reliable?

I tried UIllinois' Macaulay2, but got stuck at installation. Otherwise, I'm literally open to trying anything (provided, of course, that the software is clean/virus-free).

I don't believe this question has been asked before; I tried looking this up on MSE and couldn't find an appropriate response. If there is one, please direct me to it- thank you in advance!

Comment: Nah, Mac OSX. If need be I could get access to a PC.

Comment: There's no need, M2 is designed to work well on OS X. I suggest you spend a bit more effort on installing M2, and also install Aquamacs for a better user interface.

Comment: @Andrew I don't want to give off the impression I'm lazy or anything- I've spent way much longer than I should have trying to install M2. I'll have another go at it, but I doubt there's anything left to try

Comment: Try their web version, habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690 .

Comment: @Youngsu you should put that as an answer

Comment: I have a Mac and use Macaulay2 all the time on it without problems. If you have problems, you could try to ask on the Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/macaulay2 .

Comment: The following site came to my mind SageMath Cloud http://wstein.org/. It says it can handle both Macaulay2 and singular (and more).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try a web version of Macaulay2, http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/TryItOut/, http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/.

Comment: Not a reliable link: that site is down relatively often.

Comment: @user26857 I've noticed that the server is unstable these days. I've emailed Mike Stillman about this. It might be faster and better if you just email Mike or other people listed on the webpage. Also, the google forum mentioned above is a very helpful place for questions on Macaulay2. I believe all the authors for Macaulay2 check it often. At the same time, since I'm not part of the development team, there is not much I can tell you what's going on with the server right away.

Answer (score 5):

Try also [Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de), a computer algebra system for polynomial computations.

Answer (score 4):

You may try [CoCoA](http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/) System, Computations in Commutative Algebra

Comment: Thanks- I'll look into it right now

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`homalg`](https://homalg-project.github.io/homalg_project/), which is actually a [`GAP`](https://www.gap-system.org/) package, but it just uses [`GAP`](https://www.gap-system.org/) programming language. The main advantage of this is it can use [`Singular`](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/), [`Macaulay2`](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/), [`Maple`](https://www.maplesoft.com/), [`MAGMA`](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/), [`Sage`](http://www.sagemath.org/) as its compute machine. In other words, the objects defined in `homalg` (e.g. rings, modules, ideals, etc.) reside in `GAP`, whereas the low level computations are carried out by the underlying CAS.

`homalg` is truely object oriented, supports function overloading and operator overloading. More abstractly, you can also do category theory in `homalg`.

-- Mike